# How many different colours of LEGO bricks are there?

Tags: colour

Excluding translucent pieces, how many colours of official LEGO bricks are there?

Comment: Maybe if you quantified 'recently'. There have been some new colors in the past few years, especially with the Friends line. There are also 'old' colors in new shapes, like the pink and purple leaves in the Elves line.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [official LEGO color chart at Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/colorguide.cgi) has 111 colors listed. There are 14 listed as "transparent" (or "tr"), so - 97.

The Peeron guide also lists CMYK, RGB, HTML Hex Codes (displayed as the sample), and Pantone numbers for each.

Answer (score 25):

The latest palette [officially released by LEGO](http://www.brothers-brick.com/2010/01/28/lego-releases-its-internal-color-palette-news/) in 2010 has 51 colors in use, including 33 regular colors, 14 transparent, and 4 "effect" (silver, gold, metallic, phosphorescent).

[image: Official LEGO palette]

Of course, as 81bronco [points out](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/79), there have been a lot more, but these are the one LEGO was effectively using as of January 2010. In the few years before that, LEGO was busy rationalizing its palette of colors to eliminate seldom used colors as much as posible. Considering the downsize to 51, I don't think they've removed any more since.

Comment: According to the 2010 Company Profile presentation (http://aboutus.lego.com/en-us/factsfigures/default.aspx) there are currently "58 different colours"!

Comment: Weird. I wouldn't be surprised if they couldn't tell for sure themselves, though. And maybe the 7 missing ones are reserved colours (there's no Maersk blue in the chart, for example), or maybe they reintroduced some between the chart and the company profile.

Answer (score 22):

[This Flickr image from Brick Colorstream](https://www.flickr.com/photos/126975831@N07/15801189140) shows all the known colors of LEGO bricks, charted along a timeline of when they were available. According to that image, there was one new color in 2015, "Conductive Black".

(Click for full size)
[image: Lego color timeline]

Comment: Here's an interview with the author of that image: http://www.newelementary.com/2015/03/lego-colour-chart-reference.html

It's a fun read on how the flickr stream and image came to be.

Answer (score 11):

According to the LEGO customer service site which allows you to search by color family, there are 9 color families and 23 exact colors:

```
Color Family Exact Color
-------------------------------------------
Black        BLACK
Blue         BRIGHT BLUE
Blue         EARTH BLUE
Blue         MEDIUM BLUE
Blue         TR. BLUE
Blue         TR. LIGHT BLUE
Green        BRIGHT GREEN
Green        BRIGHT YELLOWISH GREEN
Green        DARK GREEN
Green        TR. FLUORE. GREEN
Green        TR. GREEN
Grey         DARK STONE GREY
Grey         MEDIUM STONE GREY
Orange-brown BRIGHT ORANGE
Orange-brown DARK ORANGE
Orange-brown FLAME YELLOWISH ORANGE
Orange-brown REDDISH BROWN
Orange-brown TR. BROWN
Purple       BRIGHT PURPLE
Purple       MEDIUM LILAC
Red          BRIGHT RED
Red          NEW DARK RED
Red          TR. FLUORE.REDD. ORANGE
Red          TR. RED
White        WHITE
Yellow       BRICK YELLOW
Yellow       BRIGHT YELLOW
Yellow       SAND YELLOW
Yellow       TR. YELLOW
```

http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme

Comment: Bear in mind however that some shades are considered "rare" or "exclusive" and aren't available through Pick-a-brick. Also, some shades aren't listed - search for Element ID 4505990 and you find a cup with an exact colour of "Warm Gold"

Comment: For anyone reading this answer from 2011 please note that the colours olive green, yellowish green, medium azure, medium lavender have since been added in 2012. And light aqua and lavender were added in 2011. https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp?v=0&itemType=P&itemNo=