# Is there an official LEGO brick color reference?

Tags: colour

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many different colours of lego brick are there?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-many-different-colours-of-lego-brick-are-there)

Is there a canonical reference for the different colors of LEGO bricks?

Ideally this would be a color-matching system like [Pantone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone#Original_Pantone_Color_Matching_System) or [RAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAL_(color_space_system)) but if such a reference isn't available something like [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) would be acceptable as well.

Comment: This question provides a link that includes Pantone colors.
http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-many-different-colours-of-lego-brick-are-there

Comment: Good catch, that went up while I was fetching the Wikipedia links for Pantone and RAL - I'd rather close as duplicate than delete, though, as I think this title is differently-searachable.

Answer (score 5):

Every color used in LEGO over the years is listed on the [official LEGO color chart at Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/colorguide.cgi). It also includes CMYK, RGB and Pantone references.