# What are the possible differences between LEGO elements?

Tags: technic

I'm in a technical school in the Netherlands and we received the following questions for an assignment:

1. What are the other possible differences between LEGO elements?
2. What are the different forms of LEGO elements?
3. In which different colours can the LEGO elements exist?
4. In what packaging form can the elements be found?

Where can I find information on these various questions?

Comment: Note: this question has been translated from Dutch, feel free to check the original Dutch wording in the [first revision](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/revisions/1883/1). Also, if you have some elements of answers linking to Dutch-speaking sites, I guess that's even better... Answering in Dutch might be fine too provided there's an English translation as well.

Comment: Hallo Maxime en welkom op deze site. Helaas is de site zelf voor engelstaligen bedoeld. Ik denk dat je vraag wel interessant is voor iedereen, en daarom heb ik het vertaald, maar ik vreese dat meeste antwoorden zullen in het Engels zijn. Nog iets, ik zie dat je een student, gelieve te noteren dat je meer dan 13 moet zijn om aan de site deel te nemen (ik weet niet echt welke leeftijd de studenten van een Technasium school hebben). En, ja, eigenlijk moet je wel zo veel mogelijk in het Engels kunnen deelnemen - vraag misschien hulp aan je leraar Engels.

Comment: Cheers for the attempt at translation Joubarc - I'm not sure 1 or 2 really make sense at the moment, however I'm guessing this question is really about materials? Should 2 read "What materials are LEGO elements made from?" this would be roughly consistent with 4 which is asking about packaging materials, and often relates to colours as well...

Comment: I agree that the first two questions are a bit bizarre, but I'm confident the translation is fairly accurate. That said, being a school assignment, I trust the question may be deliberately vague in order to see what answers the students will come up with. And even as such, question 2 can certainly be answered (eg. bricks, plates, technic beams, gears, axles, wheels, whatever) - question 1 make admittedly less sense (especially the "other" which puzzles me, there may be some introductory text we're missing)

Answer (score 2):

Really 4 questions in one.

To try to address question 3,

> In which different colours can the LEGO elements exist?

these links to other similar questions may help:

- [How many different colours of LEGO bricks are there?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/75/789)
- [Is there a list of colours currently in production?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1795/789)