# LEGO Brick Color Palette

Tags: colour

Have any new brick colors come out recently? I haven't seen many diverse colors and was wondering if there is still an expanding palette for the bricks being produced.

Comment: We should probably update one or other of the answers on [How many different colours of LEGO bricks are there?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/75/56) - however the Peeron list is updated as colours are seen, so it should have them all, sadly it doesn't seem to have date ranges on there for "first/last seen" although you can find one per-part: http://www.peeron.com/inv/colortable/3004?ip=0